# Consider the program output

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, undefined-behavior

Consider the program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int  x = 33;
  float y = 5;

  printf("%d %d",y,x);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 1075052544
```

I can understand the value of y coming 0 as UB but y x is coming so? [Here](http://ideone.com/qmSvSe) is an ideone sample.

Comment: Because %d expects an int not a float, use %f for floats.

Comment: Well, once you have UB, anything is allowed to happen. But are you aware that `float`s are promoted to `double` when passed to `printf`?

Comment: they are promoted to double? how ? please elaborate @DanielFischer

Comment: @akash [default argument promotions](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have undefined behaviour, anything is allowed to happen, so you can't really expect anything sensible after printing with the wrong conversion specifier.

However, in this case, we can reconstruct what most probably happened.

`printf` is a variadic function, hence its arguments undergo the *default argument promotions*. That means `float` arguments are promoted to `double` before they are passed to `printf`.

The IEEE754 `double` representation of 5 is

```
0x4014000000000000
```

encoding a sign-bit 0, an exponent of `2 + 1023 = 1025 = 0x401` and a significand of `5/4`, which, removing the hidden 1-bit becomes `0x4000000000000`.

The values printed are 0 and `1075052544 = 0x40140000`. They correspond to the low-order 32 bits of the `double` 5 and the high-order 32 bits of it, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You use incorrect formatting for `y` which is a float. In `printf`, "%d" is for integers (int) and "%f" for floating-point data (float).

This is the correct way to print `x` and `y` (provided x is int and y is float):

```
printf("%f %d", y, x);
```

As to `x`, it's *probably* (I'm not completely sure) printed incorrectly because invalid formatting is used for printing the variable before that (`y`).

Comment: that is irrelevant , i m asking for x and everybody is answering for y !

Answer (score 1):

Use `%f` for printing floating point numbers

```
printf("%f %d",y,x);
```

Comment: well this is fine , but why x is coming garbage i have used the correct specifier for it

Comment: After changing the `%d` to a `%f` I put this code as is into `main.c` and then ran `gcc main.c; ./a.out` and my output was `5.000000 33`. Exactly what you would expect. The problem may come from using ideone.